# how to change default home to the page of installed template in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

After installing the template and activating it in WordPress my site is showing the default page. how to change the home page according to the template? my template contains tiles such as about us, contact us page?

Should I do some changes in wp-include file?

**HTML of main template front page.php**

```
   <div class="page-navi">
      <a class="home-page page-transition" href="#home" onClick="gotoPageWithTrans2(0)" title="Go Home"></a>
      <a class="prev-page page-transition" href="#about" onClick="gotoPageWithTrans3(1)" title="Go To Previous Page"></a>
  </div>
  <h1>Our Team</h1>
  <nav class="submenu page3-submenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#about" class="page-transition" onClick="gotoPageWithTrans5(1)">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="current">
        <a href="#team">Our Team</a>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a href="#works" class="page-transition" onClick="gotoPageWithTrans4(3)">Our Works</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contacts" class="page-transition" onClick="gotoPageWithTrans4(4)">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#blog" class="page-transition" onClick="gotoPageWithTrans4(5)">Our Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#feedback" class="page-transition" onClick="gotoPageWithTrans4(6)">Feedback</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: i think you need a better understanding of wordpress (as i can think from your idea of what wp-include could do). Please try to find a good tutorial or you will run over a lot of further problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Log In to Admin
Select 'Reading' from 'Settings' menu.
Select  'A static page (select below)' from 'Front page displays' option.
Select any page or post added && save it.
```

Thanks